# Warum wird auffallen hier nicht konjugiert?

Tags: conjugation

> Doch es gibt einen grundlegenden Unterschied: Kopernikus greift einen
>   bereits in der Antike erwogenen, aber wieder **fallen** gelassenen
>   Gedanken **auf** und zeigt, dass sich unsere Erde nicht im Zentrum des
>   Planetenreigens befindet, sondern dass dort vielmehr die Sonne steht.

Comment: Partizipien können auch dekliniert werden, du meinst aber wohl eher *konjugiert*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Weil es nicht um auffallen geht, sondern um **aufgreifen** und *fallen lassen*.

> Doch es gibt einen grundlegenden Unterschied: Kopernikus **greift** einen bereits in der Antike erwogenen, aber wieder *fallen gelassenen* Gedanken **auf** und zeigt, dass sich unsere Erde nicht im Zentrum des Planetenreigens befindet, sondern dass dort vielmehr die Sonne steht.